# Troubles aligning ttk widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I'm not able to correctly align `ttk` widgets in the simple following application.

[image]

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.frames = []
        self.entries = []
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Trajectories")
        
        self.FOPTIONS = ['A','B','C','D']
        self.LSOURCE = StringVar()
        self.LSOURCE.set(self.FOPTIONS[0])
        self.FINDX = IntVar()
        self.FLIST = ['0']
    
        ttk.Style().configure("TFrame", padding=6, relief="flat",background="#ccc")
        
        #F0 = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding=5)
        
        ttk.Button(self.root,text='Import').grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,sticky="w")
        ttk.Combobox(self.root,textvariable=self.LSOURCE,values=self.FOPTIONS).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w") 
    
        F1 = ttk.Frame(self.root,padding=5)
        # Labels row
        ttk.Label(F1,text='Number').grid(row=0,column=0)
        ttk.Label(F1,text='File').grid(row=0,column=1)
        ttk.Label(F1,text='Alias').grid(row=0,column=2)
        ttk.Label(F1,text='Crop').grid(row=0,column=3)
        ttk.Label(F1,text='Show').grid(row=0,column=4)
        
        # Fields row
        ttk.Combobox(F1,textvariable=self.FINDX,values=self.FLIST,width=5).grid(row=1,column=0) # File
        ttk.Entry(F1,width=50).grid(row=1,column=1,padx=3,sticky='w')
        ttk.Entry(F1,width=15).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='w') # Alias
        ttk.Checkbutton(F1).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='we') # Crops
        ttk.Checkbutton(F1).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky='we')  # Show
        
        F1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2) 
        
        Button(self.root, text="Create",command=self.draw).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
        
    def draw(self):
        print("Draw pressed")

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The troubles are:

(i) with the first `ttk.Combobox()` and

(ii) `Checkbuttons()` under "Crop" and "Show" labels. I have tried many strategies but:

- I haven't been able to place the `ttk.Combobox()` completely aligned to the left just close to the button "Import".
- `Checkbuttons()` are without text and are not centered with respect to the labels in the row above.

The desirable situation should be something similar to the graphic below.
[image: Desirable situation]

I have tried some variant encapsulating the first row into a frame but nothing changes. The second row with labels and the third row with the fields are encapsulated within a frame just to group a variable number of additional rows. the changes using sticky values did not produce any effect. Just I don't understand in this example how `grid()` is working in such a way and why the `Combobox` does not justify to the left("w") and why the `"ew"` does not center `Checkbuttons()` inside the cells.

If I try to grid the "Import" button as (row=0,column=0,sticky="w") an the
ttk.Combobox().grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w") as suggested in one of the comments I get:

[image]

Comment: Try changing the `grid()` of the combobox to `grid(row=0,column=0)`. And I dont quite understand what you meant by _"Checkbuttons() are without text"_. You are not giving it any text, then why do you expect it to show any text?

Comment: I mean there is no labels with the parameter "text"

Comment: If I do Combobox().grid(row=0,column=0) the Button "Import" and the Combobox appear overlapped !

Comment: Even more striking, if I use instead the tk version then the checkboxes are correctly centered !!!

Comment: I dont think the button and combobox will overlap because the button is set to be on the west of the cell and the other half will be taken by combobox.

Comment: Yes this is what happens, please see the last figure I have added to the question.

Comment: Try without the sticky, `ttk.Combobox().grid(row=0,column=0)`

Comment: It works better but still some padding space is present.

Comment: `tkinter` is not a great designing tool, but if you work it out properly, it can do great things.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution (although not 100% satified) has been to encapsulate the first row into a frame and using tk.Checkbutton() instead of ttk.Checkbutton() for the checkboxes.

```
F0 = ttk.Frame(self.root)       
ttk.Button(F0,text='Import').grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,sticky="w")
ttk.Combobox(F0,.....).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w") 
F0.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
```

and using tk instead of tkk widgets for Checkbutton

```
# ttk.Checkbutton(F1).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='we')
tk.Checkbutton(F1).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='we')
```

In my opinion is very strange that ttk does not obey "sticky" behaviour correctly (maybe a bug ?).

Comment: It's not a bug. I'm not 100% sure what you're referring to, but the grid geometry manager has been around for a couple decades, if there was a bug in it someone would have found it years ago.

Comment: Probably you are true but just try the difference between the tk and ttk versions as the case I have reported here and you will see that they respond differently, what does not mean that all ttk widgets have this problem. In my opinion is not a matter of the grid() but the way ttk.Checkbutton() implements it.

Comment: The `ttk.Checkbutton` doesn't have a separate implementation of `grid` - all widgets share the same implementation.

Comment: Please, any hint how to suppress the label space through the style layout ? I did not find how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the combobox isn't immediately to the right of the import button is because column 0 is wider than you think. You can see that the combobox is right up against the button if you temporarily comment out `F1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)`

It is that wide because you put `F1` in column 0 and have it span two columns, so by definition column 0 and column 1 together must be as wide as `F1`.

One simple solution is to have a third column that is empty, and have it take up the extra space. Do that by having `F1` span three columns, and giving a non-zero weight to the third column. That column will then get all extra space, so columns 0 and 1 will be only as large as the largest item in that column.

The problem with the checkbuttons is simply that there's space for the label whether you have a label or not, so the actual checkbox is offset to the left. Since you are using a ttk `Checkbutton`, you can completely remove the label from the style layout for that widget if you want the checkbutton to be centered.

It should look something like this:

```
ttk.Style().layout("CustomCheckbutton", [('Checkbutton.button', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])
...
ttk.Checkbutton(F1, style="CustomCheckbutton").grid(row=1,column=3) # Crops
ttk.Checkbutton(F1, style="CustomCheckbutton").grid(row=1,column=4)  # Show
```